# jasmine2: how to handle failing beforeAll

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

My jasmine2/protractor test look like this

```
var testUserId = null;

describe("user test", function() {
  beforeAll(function(done) {
    createTestUser().
      .then(function(userId){testUserId = userId})
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);

  it("should do stuff with the test user", function(done) {
    // bla bla
  });

  afterAll(function(done) {
    deleteTestUser(testUserId).
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });

})
```

createTestUser and deleteTestUser return promises. If a problem occur they reject with an error message. May Problem is now, that the tests get started even if the error occurs in beforeAll. And I get

```
Failures:
1) should do stuff with the test user
Message: [my error message from beforeAll]
```

If there are many tests it tries to perform all of them and fail with the very sam error message. Is it possible to prevent it from executing the tests if the beforeAll function fails?

Thx!

("jasmine-core": "2.8.0", "protractor": "5.2.1")

---

Edit:

It's not exactly what I was asking for but at least I found a solution to keep the amount of error messages close like this:

```
var testUserId = null;
describe("user test", function() {
  beforeAll(function(done) {
    createTestUser().
      .then(function(userId){testUserId = userId})
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail("test user could not be created"));

  it("should do stuff with the test user", function(done) {
    if (testUserId) {
      // bla bla
    } else {
      done();
  });
```

This way I get a least only the correct error message ("test user could not be created") and not the ones of the unmet expectations in "// bla bla" (Naturally I still get one for each *it*, but whatever). I also wrapped the functions in a function-factory so that I don't have to write the if-condition everytime.

Comment: why aren't you mocking the dependency that `createTestUser` creates? a test shouldn't fail because a dependency failed. isolate yourself!

Comment: Thats right. Let's just say it would mean a way too big change in an architecture which is not made by me. In the realz there is not only a testuser created but many other stuff, but a uses a real backend with database and stuff for that and this might go wrong. yes, yes, I know..

Comment: it sounds like an x-y problem then. you can do anything with the items in your test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, [`jasmine` does not support that](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/577) despite the attention:

> Skipping out in the middle of the spec run (this issue) is a bit more
>   complicated, because depending on the type of error, Jasmine probably
>   still needs to run any afterEach (or afterAll depending) to cleanup
>   state for the next spec. This would then require the QueueRunner to
>   know which of the functions it is given are setup and teardown and not
>   just have a list of functions to call.

One option would be to use the "fail fast" option which can be done by using one of the third-party libraries like [`jasmine-fail-fast`](https://github.com/Updater/jasmine-fail-fast) or [`protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale`](https://github.com/radialanalytics/protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale).

There are though some other workarounds, like manually checking if there was a preceding failure in the `it()` functions:

- [Jasmine/Protractor: stop test on failure in beforeEach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23137793/771848)

Comment: Am I correct, that both plugins force the whole testing process to stop on one fail or only the current describe block (which would be desired)?

Comment: @Paflow yeah, unfortunately the whole test execution is gonna stop. Kind of like a workaround mostly.