# How can I prevent tests execution in beforeAll block in jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Before all my tests (running in jasmine under protractor) I have to login to my system and if login fails I should not run any test. But even when I use `proccess.exit` (which is  node feature to halt program execution), tests are still executed and all failed .

```
beforeAll(function(done){
    mainPage.resize();
    loginPage.login(env.regularUser).then(function(){
        mainPage.navigate();
        mainPage.waitLoading();
        done();
    }, function(){
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

How can I prevent tests execution in `beforeAll` block?

Comment: `beforeAll` doesn't take the async `done` param (see http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-49)

Comment: @hankduan, in fact `beforeAll` does take one promise parameter, at least in jasmine 2.2.1. Check it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is the same or a related problem to:

- [Does jasmine-node offer any type of "fail fast" option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562817/does-jasmine-node-offer-any-type-of-fail-fast-option)
- [Feature Request - fail-fast option](https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode/issues/20)
- [Bail on first failure](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/414)
- [--fail-fast CLI option](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/499)
- [Quitting on first failure](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/550)

In other words, this is something a testing framework (in this case `jasmine`) should have. At the moment, this is an *open feature request*.

As a current workaround, use [`jasmine-bail-fast`](https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast) third-party package.

Comment: I solwed this with expection throwing

Comment: @SET can you please share your code to prevent tests execution in beforeAll block please.